# Is Redmine limited to being installed on your own servers only? No cloud plans?

Tags: project-management, cloud

I am a current user of Unfuddle and heard of Redmine. I went to their site but I saw that they are offering only downloading of Redmine and installing it on your own server. I haven't seen they offer paid cloud service.

I'd rather pay them monthly fee for the cloud service than having to take care of another thing in my work (installing, updating, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last company I worked for used redmine hosted at https://www.hostedredmine.com/. Looking into it now, it appears it's actually a third-party service. [Redmine's wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/CommercialOfferings#Hosting-and-Hosted-versions-Software-As-A-Service) lists a couple other alternatives:

> - BitNami Cloud Hosting makes it easy to host your own Redmine installation in the Cloud. It provides automatic backup and monitoring and allows you to scale up or down your server as needed. We have a free developer plan which together with the AWS free tier allows you to run a server 24/7 for free during one year.
> - Get Redmine Hosting provides unlimited Redmine projects and source control repos starting at $12/month. Satisfaction Guaranteed.
> - Planio Redmine Hosting is a Redmine hosting service which comes with hosted Subversion (SVN) and Git repositories. Planio runs on servers with certified security in a high-performance data center with multiple redundant uplinks. There is a free plan, paid plans start at €9 / month.

Answer (score -1):

There's a hosted ALM (or in their own lingo Software Development Ecosystem) solution which includes Redmine : http://clinkerhq.com/products#cloud